# Can't create sessions for some of my STI User types using Blizzard's omniauth-bnet gem

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm working on a Rails 5 app using the `omniauth-bnet` gem, not `devise`, have a Single Sign On through that gem, and have a few User types, using Single Table Inheritance. For whatever reason, the admin type can login fine, but the average User cannot create a session. Here's some of the relevant code.

items_controller.rb:

```
before_action :check_authorization, except: [:show]
before_action :check_for_email, except: [:show]
...
private

def check_authorization
  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

def check_for_email
  unless current_user.email
    redirect_to signup_add_email_url
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  begin
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    flash[:success] = "Well met, #{@user.name}!"
  rescue
    flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to create your 
account..."
  end
  redirect_to items_path
end
...
```

admin_user.rb:

```
class AdminUser < User
end
```

normal_user.rb:

```
class NormalUser < User
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
...

class << self
  def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
    user = find_or_create_by(name: auth_hash['info']['battletag'], uid: 
auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
    user.name = auth_hash['info']['battletag']
    user.uid = auth_hash['uid']
    user.token = auth_hash['credentials']['token']
    user.save!
    user
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
...
# Auth
get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
...
```

The logs show that my NormalUser type session never gets created. Yet the AdminUser type doesn't have any problem logging in...

Any ideas? I've tried everything I can google or think of.

Comment: Devise is probably complaining that the email is nil.

Comment: @JoshBrody I don't think that's the case. I have tried accounts that have email confirmed via `rails console` and they also do not work.

Comment: _"NormalUser type session never gets created"_ - Do you mean you are not able to create a `NormalUser` record OR not able to sign it in?

Comment: @jagdeep Not able to sign it in. The records exist. I used to be able to sign them in but don't see what changed via git and am unsure when it changed.

Comment: I should also add that I'm not using Devise.